# awk insert rows of one file as new columns to every nth rows of another file

Tags: bash, awk

Let's keep *n*=3 here, and say I have two files:

`file1.txt`

```
a b c row1
d e f row2
g h i row3
j k l row4
m n o row5
o q r row6
s t u row7
v w x row8
y z Z row9
```

`file2.txt`

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I would like to merge the two files into a new_file.txt:

`new_file.txt`

```
a b c 2 3
d e f 2 3
g h i 2 3
j k l 5 6
m n o 5 6
o q r 5 6
s t u 8 9
v w x 8 9
y z Z 8 9
```

Currently I do this as follows (there are also slow bash `for` or `while` loop solutions, of course): `awk '1;1;1' file2.txt > tmp2.txt` and then something like `awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$2" "$3;next};{$NF=a[FNR]};1' tmp2.txt file1.txt > new_file.txt` for the case listed in my question.

Or put these in one line: `awk '1;1;1' file2.txt | awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$2" "$3;next};{$NF=a[FNR]};1' - file1.txt > new_file.txt`. But these do not look elegant at all...

I am looking for a more elegant one liner (perhaps awk) that can effectively do this.

In the real case, let's say for example I have 9 million rows in input file1.txt and 3 million rows in input file2.txt and I would like to append columns 2 and 3 of the first row of file2.txt as the new last columns of the first 3 rows of file1.txt, columns 2 and 3 of the second row of file2.txt as the same new last columns of the next 3 rows of file1.txt, etc, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, row1, row2, etc are part of the actual data in input file.

Comment: And your current attempt at coding this looks like ...?

Comment: ... and describe the algorithm to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, see [mywiki.wooledge - Process Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) for details on `<()` syntax

```
$ # transforming file2
$ cut -d' ' -f2-3 file2.txt | sed 'p;p'
2 3
2 3
2 3
5 6
5 6
5 6
8 9
8 9
8 9

$ # then paste it together with required fields from file1
$ paste -d' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1-3 file1.txt) <(cut -d' ' -f2-3 file2.txt | sed 'p;p')
a b c 2 3
d e f 2 3
g h i 2 3
j k l 5 6
m n o 5 6
o q r 5 6
s t u 8 9
v w x 8 9
y z Z 8 9
```

Speed comparison, time shown for two consecutive runs

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $_ x 1000000' file1.txt > f1
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $_ x 1000000' file2.txt > f2
$ du -h f1 f2
95M f1
18M f2


$ time paste -d' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1-3 f1) <(cut -d' ' -f2-3 f2 | sed 'p;p') > t1

real    0m1.362s
real    0m1.154s

$ time awk '1;1;1' f2 | awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$2" "$3;next};{$NF=a[FNR]};1' - f1 > t2

real    0m12.088s
real    0m13.028s

$ time awk '{ 
         if (c==3) c=0; 
         printf "%s %s %s ",$1,$2,$3; 
         if (!c++){ getline < "f2"; f4=$2; f5=$3 } 
         printf "%s %s\n",f4,f5 
     }' f1 > t3

real    0m13.629s
real    0m13.380s

$ time awk '{ 
         if (c==3) c=0; 
         main_fields=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3; 
         if (!c++){ getline < "f2"; f4=$2; f5=$3 } 
         printf "%s %s %s\n", main_fields, f4, f5 
     }' f1 > t4

real    0m13.265s 
real    0m13.896s

$ diff -s t1 t2
Files t1 and t2 are identical
$ diff -s t1 t3
Files t1 and t3 are identical
$ diff -s t1 t4
Files t1 and t4 are identical
```

Comment: The interesting metric isn't really the performance on a static set, it's at which point the I/O overhead starts to dominate over the CPU overhead of the respective solutions, on the OP's hardware.  But +1 for going to great lengths to show how to do the metrics.

Comment: I like both solutions (the other being RomanPerekhrest's)! May I "accept" both? If not, I go for Sundeep for speed and comparison.

Comment: @VXtal see help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .. also, I'd suggest to wait for few more hours/days, interesting questions generally get more answers..

Comment: Instead of `cut | sed`, you could use only sed: `sed 's/^ *[^ ]\+ //;p;p'`

Comment: @F.Hauri that takes almost double the time compared to cut+sed because of regex

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ 
         if (c==3) c=0; 
         main_fields=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3; 
         if (!c++){ getline < "file2.txt"; f4=$2; f5=$3 } 
         printf "%s %s %s\n", main_fields, f4, f5 
     }' file1.txt
```

- `c` - variable reflecting *nth* coefficient
- **`getline < file`** - reads the next record from *file*
- `f4=$2; f5=$3` - contain the values of the 2nd and 3rd fields from currently read record of `file2.txt`

---

The output:

```
a b c 2 3
d e f 2 3
g h i 2 3
j k l 5 6
m n o 5 6
o q r 5 6
s t u 8 9
v w x 8 9
y z Z 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still a lot slower than Sundeep's cut&paste code on the 100,000 lines test (8s vs 21s on my laptop) but perhaps easier to understand than the other Awk solution. (I had to play around for a bit before getting the indexing right, though.)

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[FNR] = $2 " " $3; next }
    { print $1, $2, $3, a[1+int((FNR-1)/3)] }' file2.txt file1.txt
```

This simply keeps (the pertinent part of) `file2.txt` in memory and then reads `file1.txt` and writes out the combined lines.  That also means it is limited by available memory, whereas Roman's solution will scale to basically arbitrarily large files (as long as each line fits in memory!) but slightly faster (I get 28s real time for Roman's script with Sundeep's 100k test data).

Comment: This is nice!!! I must admit that I was indeed looking for the second part of your solution, i.e. the `a[1+int((FNR-1)/3)]` part. Cannot go wrong with speed (and almost pure bash) while `awk` is also flexible for combining with other `awk` functions and/or for conditional situations. Thank you all! I hope you and RomanPerekhrest won't mind that I accept Sundeep's solution.